# Calling an Enum from another Class

Tags: java, enums

I am working on a Deck project and I have a Card class with two enums for it:

```
package exercise4;
public class Card
{
    public enum Suit
    {
        HEARTS,SPADES,CLUBS,DIAMONDS
    }

    public enum CardValue
    {
        ACE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE,TEN,JACK,QUEEN,KING
    }
    private Suit s;
    private CardValue cv;
    other methods...
}
```

Ok thats right for Card class, the problem is that I have to call them from another class, but NetBeans doesn't allow me to do this:

```
Card testcard=new Card(CardValue.ACE,Suit.HEARTS);
```

and NetBeans force me to do this:

```
Card testcard=new Card(Card.CardValue.ACE,Card.Suit.HEARTS);
```

but on test files provided by my teachers they call enums this way and it must work:

```
package exercise4;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class BarajaTest 

{
    @Test
    public void testGetCard() {
        int position = 0;
        Deck instance = new Deck();
        Card expResult = new (CardValue.ACE,Suit.HEARTS);
        Card result = instance.getCard(position);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);}
}
```

What am I doing bad? :/

Thanks

Comment: Why did you nest your enums types in `Card` class? Are you required to do so?

Comment: Yes, it must be in Card

Comment: I nest enums quite a lot... inside classes and inside OTHER enums! With ECLIPSE, i have no problems accessing them on other classes...

Answer (score 7):

You can use `CardValue` and `Suit` directly by simply importing them, same as any other class/enum/interface.

```
package stackoverflow;

import exercise4.Card;
import exercise4.Card.CardValue;
import exercise4.Card.Suit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card testcard = new Card(CardValue.ACE, Suit.HEARTS);
        // more code
    }
}
```

Of course, you could also just make `CardValue` and `Suit` top-level enums by moving them to their own source files: `CardValue.java` and `Suit.java`.

As others pointed out, you can also import the enum values statically:

```
package stackoverflow;

import exercise4.Card;
import static exercise4.Card.CardValue.*;
import static exercise4.Card.Suit.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Card testcard = new Card(ACE, HEARTS);
        // more code
    }
}
```